# Angular2 HttpParams not sent as expected

Tags: angular, http-parameters

When sending a GET request with Query Parameters using Angular2 http, the sent parameters aren't sent as I expect. Rather than the standard key value pair e.g.

`key1=val1&key2=val2`

It's being sent as the HttpParams object e.g.

`%7B%22param%22:%key1%22,%22value%22:%22val1%22,%22op%22:%22a%22%7D`

*decoded:
`{"param":"key1","value":"val1","op":"a"}`

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
  getAllPlayers(fantasyFormat: string, draftFormat: string): Observable<Player[]> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('fantasyFormat', fantasyFormat);
    params = params.append('draftFormat', draftFormat);

    return this.http.get(this.playersUrl, {params: params})
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
```

Not sure what is going wrong here, seems to be consistent with other examples I've followed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 getAllPlayers(fantasyFormat: string, draftFormat: string): Observable<Player[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.playersUrl}?fantasyFormat=${fantasyFormat}&draftFormat=${draftFormat}`)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
```

I'd suggest to do it like this. I don't see a need to use HttpParams here. Also I never used them in my code. I'll read about them, but it seems to me that there's no difference except syntax and URI encoding between those cases.

Comment: Thanks @vitalii-chmovzh. Adding the params as part of the URL does work. HttpParams is available for a reason, would love to see how it is used properly.